# Setting parameters for mean filter

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the ROS [filters](http://wiki.ros.org/filters) to low-pass filter data from a joysitck using the mean filter. I have a node that accepts the commands from the joystick on the "/joy" topic, filters the data, and publishes on another topic. When I try to setup the filters, they always fail with the error :

> MultiChannelMeanFilter did not find param number_of_observations

I tried to load the YAML file with the filter configurations (as shown [here](http://wiki.ros.org/filters/MeanFilter)) in the global namespace, as well as in the namespace of the node using roslaunch, but neither seems to work.

The code I am using to configure the filters:

```
    class JoystickRelay{
        public:
                JoystickRelay();

        private:
                ros::NodeHandle nh_;
                ros::NodeHandle pnh_;
                ros::Publisher cmd_pub_;
                ros::Subscriber vel_sub_;

                bool enable_filter_;

                void velCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy);
                filters::MultiChannelMeanFilter<double> filter_;
};

JoystickRelay::JoystickRelay(): pnh_(ros::NodeHandle("~")), enable_filter_(false) {


        cmd_pub_ = nh_.advertise<std_msgs::Float64MultiArray>("command", 100);
        vel_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("/joy", 1, &JoystickRelay::velCallback, this);

        // Check if filtering is enabled        
        if(pnh_.getParam("filter", enable_filter_)){
                if(enable_filter_){
                        filter_.configure(); // Configure the filter
                }
        }
}
```

Am I missing something while configuring the filters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284761/setting-parameters-for-mean-filter/) by [aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/34046/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-08**:
If you post your launch file & .yaml file it might be easier to troubleshoot. You could also try running some of the test filters in [this repo](https://github.com/ijt/filters).

**Comment by [aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/34046/aditya/) on 2018-03-08**:
Thanks stevejp for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get this working. I have noted the details in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code and other relevant details are being added here for anybody else who might be facing the same problem.

joy_filter_node.cpp:

```
#include "filters/mean.h"

class JoystickRelay {
    public:
        JoystickRelay();

    private:
        ros::NodeHandle pnh_;

        filters::MultiChannelFilterBase<double> filter_;
}

JoystickRelay::JoystickRelay() : pnh_(ros::NodeHandle("~")) {
    
        filter_ = new filters::MultiChannelMeanFilter<double>
        int channels = 2;
                
        filter_->configure(channels, "FifthOrder", pnh_);

        // Add the other initialization code
}
```

Notice that the object "filter_" is a pointer to the base class "filters::MultiChannelFilterBase". The private node handle "pnh_" is used for configuration as the parameters from the config file are loaded in the private namespace of the node.

The configuration file -- filter.yaml :

```
FifthOrder:
  name : my_filter
  type: MultiChannelMeanFilterDouble
  params: 
    number_of_observations : 5
```

And the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="joystick_relay" pkg="joystick_relay" type="joystick_relay_node"
        output="screen" ns="/robot/position_controller/" >
    <rosparam file="$(find joystick_relay)/config/filter.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/34046/aditya/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1